# Substitution regex

Tags: regex, perl

I want to substitute all white space that precedes the class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, with `$`.

```
$string = "STRING sDir = sDrive";
$string =~ s/\s(?=[A-Za-z0-9_])/ \$/;
```

It only matches one time and produces:

```
STRING $sDir = sDrive;
```

Comment: You can use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: @eugene No, you can't use `\w` as a synonym for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. If you mean `\w` with all its implications, then use `\w`. If you mean `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, then use `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: you can if you know you're dealing with ascii, though.

Comment: @sreservoir "Say what you mean, mean what you say".

Comment: the qualify it to tell perl you're dealing with ascii! though it is hard to be sure, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `g` flag for your regex:

```
$string = "STRING sDir = sDrive";
$string =~ s/\s(?=[A-Za-z0-9_])/ \$/g;
```

so that the `s///` will operate for every match for your pattern.

Default Perl behavior is to perform the substitution once.

The `g` flag tells it to perform the substitution for every occurrence.

Comment: This will replace tabs, newlines and other whitespace with a 'space' too, so be careful. Or just replace the regex with `s/(\s)(?=[A-Za-z0-9_])/$1\$/g`. Also you could try `s/(?<=\s)(?=[A-Za-z0-9_])/\$/g`. Both are untested, but the former should work for sure.

Answer (score 3):

To match multiple times, use the /g flag:

```
$string = "STRING sDir = sDrive";
$string =~ s/\s(?=[A-Za-z0-9_])/ \$/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

if I think you mean what you mean:

```
s/\s+\b/ \$/g;
```

this removes all whitespace before (so `'   a'` -> `' $a'`) and \b is an assertion of either `(?=(?<=\W)\w)` or `(?=(<=\w)\W_`; \s is always `\W`, and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` matches the common definition of `\w`, so it matches your `(?=[...])`.

(of course, if you're dealing with character sets in which `\w` is not the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, you'll have to substitute `\b` for the assertion.)